# Visual Basic https get request - Accept SSL

Tags: vb.net, ssl, https, get, request

I am trying to make a https Request with Visual Basic (Visual Basic Express 2010).
If I am trying with http - everything works fine.
If I try https - it throw an error, because of the SSL Certificate.

If I try to add this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
  New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications)
```

It says "AcceptAllCertifications" is not declared. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wired up a handler for the event, but didn't add the method.  Try adding this to your class:

```
Public Function AcceptAllCertifications(
    sender As Object,
    certificate As X509Certificate,
    chain As X509Chain,
    sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors
) As Boolean

     Return True

End Function
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  Please up vote and/or accept this as the correct answer if you don't mind.